# replace IDs from GROUP_CONCAT column with names

Tags: mysql

I have three tables which I successfully joined with the following sql query

```
SELECT `bonuses`.`id`, `bonuses`.`bonus_name`, `bonuses`.`size`, creatorName.`name`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bonus_user.user_id ORDER BY bonus_user.user_id SEPARATOR ', ') as bonusUsers from `bonuses`
inner join `users` as creatorName on `bonuses`.`created_from` = creatorName.`id`
inner join `bonus_user` on `bonuses`.`id` = `bonus_user`.`bonus_id`
group by `bonuses`.`id`
```

The result I get is as following. As a further step I want to replace the ids in the column "bonusUsers" by the names from the users table. How do I manage this?

```
+----+--------------+------+--------------+--------------+
| id |  bonus_name  | size |     name     |  bonusUsers  |
+----+--------------+------+--------------+--------------+
| 3  | Bonus Test 3 |   5  |     Test1    |    1, 2, 3   |
| 4  | Bonus Test 4 |   3  |     Test1    |    1, 2, 3   |
+----+--------------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

**users**

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Test1 |
| 2  | Test2 |
| 3  | Test3 |
+----+-------+
```

**bonuses**

```
+----+--------------+------+--------------+
| id |  bonus_name  | size | created_from |
+----+--------------+------+--------------+
| 1  | Bonus Test 1 |   1  |       1      |
| 2  | Bonus Test 2 |   1  |       1      |
| 3  | Bonus Test 3 |   5  |       1      |
| 4  | Bonus Test 4 |   3  |       1      |
+----+--------------+------+--------------+
```

**bonus_user**

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | bonus_id | bonus_user |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  |     3    |      1     |
| 2  |     3    |      2     |
| 3  |     3    |      3     |
| 4  |     4    |      1     |
| 5  |     4    |      2     |
| 6  |     4    |      3     |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve with the query? Add the desired results for the sample data you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do another join with users table

```
SELECT `b`.`id`, `b`.`bonus_name`, `b`.`size`, u.`name`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bu1.`name` ORDER BY bu.user_id SEPARATOR ', ') as bonusUsers 
from `bonuses` b
inner join `users` as u on `b`.`created_from` = u.`id`
inner join `bonus_user` bu on `b`.`id` = `bu`.`bonus_id`
inner join `users` as bu1 on `bu`.`user_id` = bu1.`id`
group by `b`.`id`, `b`.`bonus_name`, `b`.`size`, u.`name`
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06c4dbb/3)

Comment: Why do we need to do a join when there is a users table already in the join?

Comment: @cdaiga Because first join is with `created_from` of bonus table to know the bonus user names which are linked via `bonus_user` you need additional join, hope that clears out your query

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid That did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You need to aliase the users table and join it to the bonus_user tables to get the name of the user from the aliased table

```
SELECT `bonuses`.`id`, `bonuses`.`bonus_name`, `bonuses`.`size`, creatorName.`name`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_names.name ORDER BY bonus_user.user_id SEPARATOR ', ') as bonusUsers from `bonuses`
inner join `users` as creatorName on `bonuses`.`created_from` = creatorName.`id`
inner join `bonus_user` on `bonuses`.`id` = `bonus_user`.`bonus_id`
inner join `users AS user_names` on `bonus_user`.`bonus_user` = `user_names`.`id`
group by `bonuses`.`id`
```

This may help as well https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Do not down vote my answer without giving an explanation

Comment: I agree with that clause, however leveling up score